# Crash when trying to remove object from ArrayList

Tags: android, object, crash, arraylist

im having a problem i havent been able to figure out a solution to. Im making a small game where the object in _sballs ArrayList will be deleted if collided with another object called ball.
the problem i've encountered is that when the collision occur and when i attempt to remove the object from the ArrayList, the application crashes.

```
for(GObject sballgraphic : _sballs){
            Coordinates sballcoords = sballgraphic.getCoords();
            if(coords.getY() - coords._height > sballcoords.getY() + sballcoords._height && coords.getX() - coords._width > sballcoords.getX() + sballcoords._width){
                _sballs.remove(sballgraphic);
            }
        }
```

So the code compares the balls coordinates with all the sballs objects to check if there is a collision, then tries to remove the sball.

What is the problem here? :)

Comment: post stack trace from logcat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing that the "crash" is a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

It is happening because you are trying to remove from a collection while you are iterating over it with an iterator (the internal workings of the enhanced for).

Your choices are:

1. Iterate using an index (old-style `for( i=0; i<_sballs.size(); i++ )`)
2. Iterate using an iterator explicitly, and use the iterator's `remove()` method.
3. Remember which items to remove by putting them into another list, and then use `removeAll()` after the loop is finished.

Comment: This is the correct answer, I would go with option 2 as I feel it is the most robust and cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You cant do such operation because you are modifying the same `_sballs` onwhich you are iterating too.

```
ArrayList<GObject> _sballs;
ArrayList<GObject> _sballsForRemove;

for(GObject sballgraphic : _sballs){
            Coordinates sballcoords = sballgraphic.getCoords();
            if(coords.getY() - coords._height > sballcoords.getY() + sballcoords._height && coords.getX() - coords._width > sballcoords.getX() + sballcoords._width){
                _sballsForRemove.add(sballgraphic);
            }
        }
_sballs.removeAll(_sballsForRemove);
```